# Evaluate integrals trapezoid rule using lists

Tags: python, list, integral, numerical-integration

I'm trying to write a formula for trapezoid rule from scratch. I'm not that familiar with python yet so I'm strugguling a bit. I have an expression I wish to integrate, which I wrote as a list called square.

I'm in the part of writing the integrals already:

```
square = []                        #Create empty list
for i in range(0, len(dos)):
     square.append(dos[i]*dist[i]) #Multiplication from inside the integral

s1 = 0
s2 = 0
for i in square[i] != square[1] and square[-1]:
    s1 += s1 + 0.01 * square[i]
else:
    s2 += s2 + 0.01 * 0.5 * square[i]
        
print(s1,s2)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
for i in square[i] != square[1] and square[-1]:

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Anyone knows what can be wrong with the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do in `for i in square[i] != square[1] and square[-1]:` you want to iterate AND set a condition it seems

Comment: Yes, I am trying to say that if the element i on the list square is different to both the first and last element, then it calculates the sum as s1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `for` loop **and** the `if` statement then, also you used `+=` so you don't need to add `s1` in th right operand because that will add it twice

```
# equivalent
s1 += square[i]
s1 = s1 + square[i]
```

```
s1 = 0
s2 = 0
for i in range(len(square)):
    if square[i] != square[0] and square[i] != square[-1]:
        s1 += 0.01 * square[i]
    else:
        s2 += 0.01 * 0.5 * square[i]
```

---

With tome tips to get cleaner code

- `zip` to create `square` list, to iterate both on `dos` and `dist` lists
- iterate on `square` by elements on not its indices
- use `in` instead of the double condition

```
square = [do * di for do, di in zip(dos, dist)]

s1 = 0
s2 = 0
for elt in square:
    if elt not in (square[0], square[-1]):
        s1 += 0.01 * elt
    else:
        s2 += 0.01 * 0.5 * elt
```